# How can I track history of all GRANTS on a specific object in a schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, sql-grant

I create a table every week ( ALTERYX override ) and assign a SELECT  grant to a role . Mysteriously in the last 6 months , the business user has called ( 2-3 times) and said SELECT access missing . How can I track the history of a specific  grant on that object so that I can understand which process and when it was dropped

BTW I know how to track a grant which clearly shows the SELECT is available on that object after table creation ( only latest it tells )

> SELECT GRANTOR, GRANTEE, OBJECT_CATALOG, OBJECT_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, PRIVILEGE_TYPE, IS_GRANTABLE, CREATED
> FROM EDP_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES

Answer (score 0):

You can query the QUERY_HISTORY view to find what's altering the privileges on that table for that role. You'll have to use freeform text matching on keywords such as the table name, the verb type (alter, revoke), and the role name. You can do something like this:

```
select  * 
from    "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
where   START_TIME > current_date - 180
    and  (QUERY_TEXT ilike '%revoke%' or QUERY_TEXT ilike '%alter%')
    and  QUERY_TEXT ilike '%table <TABLE_NAME>%'
;
```

This will search through the last 180 days. Depending on the number of statements run on the account, it could take a while to complete. If you know it's happened more recently, you can change the date range.

Also check for the table being dropped and created or a "create or replace" statement on the table.

You can also use the QUERY_TYPE column to filter on specific types such as ALTER, GRANT, CREATE, etc. and filter out others.

Comment: Do you think it would be good to include 'COPY GRANTS' which may pick up create statements ?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Comment: That's a good point, but probably more important to look for clones lacking copy grants. Tracking down these things is usually an iterative process.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pivot showing roles broken by priv type :-)

```
select
*
from
(
    select
        object_name,
        PRIVILEGE_TYPE,
        listagg(distinct grantee, ',') grantee,
        count(distinct grantee) grantees
    from
        SKYLAKE_DEV_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES
    group by
        1,
        2
) a pivot (
    sum(grantees) for PRIVILEGE_TYPE in (
        'CREATE FUNCTION',
        'UPDATE',
        'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE',
        'CREATE MASKING POLICY',
        'TRUNCATE',
        'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE',
        'INSERT',
        'CREATE SCHEMA',
        'CREATE PIPE',
        'SELECT',
        'CREATE FILE FORMAT',
        'OWNERSHIP',
        'REBUILD',
        'ADD SEARCH OPTIMIZATION',
        'DELETE',
        'MODIFY',
        'CREATE STREAM',
        'CREATE SEQUENCE',
        'CREATE TABLE',
        'CREATE STAGE',
        'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW',
        'REFERENCES',
        'CREATE TASK',
        'USAGE',
        'MONITOR',
        'CREATE VIEW',
        'CREATE PROCEDURE'
    )
)
```